# iOS HealthKit track steps and distance during session

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I'm building an app that has the ability to start/stop/save sessions. When a user begins a session, I would like to track steps and distance via the HealthKit api. How can I achieve this? Keep in mind I would like to update the app with the step and distance counter dynamically throughout the session and not just get final results once session has been completed. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just call something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26855385/how-do-i-download-healthkit-step-and-distance-data) whenever you need to refresh the data?

Comment: @ILikeTau I have tried that and when I begin a session and then walk around for a few minutes and then end the session and make that call for the steps it always returns 0